# Infinispan write behind? What am i doing wrong

Tags: scala, infinispan

I have a small test in which I am trying to chalk out the time taken by Infinispan in a local cache and then in a local cache with a write behind.

Surprisingly, the time taken in a local cache to put 8M entries is around 27 sec and to do a get it is 1 millisec. That is good. However, as soon as I enable the write behind the does not even end in 30 minutes. I am sure there is something which is terribly wrong with the configuration.

I have used 5.3.0 Final and 5.2.7 final.

The configurations are pasted here

```
<namedCache name="LocalWithWriteBehind">
    <loaders shared="false">
        <loader class="org.infinispan.loaders.file.FileCacheStore"
            fetchPersistentState="true" ignoreModifications="false"
            purgeOnStartup="false">
            <properties>
                <property name="location" value="${java.io.tmpdir}" />
            </properties>
            <!-- write-behind configuration starts here -->
            <async enabled="true" threadPoolSize="500" />
            <!-- write-behind configuration ends here -->
        </loader>
    </loaders>
</namedCache>
```

If you would like to see the Scala App, see the code here http://pastebin.com/PSiJFFiZ

Answer (score 0):

The file cache store before Infinispan 6.0 was very slow. Please upgrade to Infinispan 6.0.0.Final, and enable the single file cache store as indicated [here](http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_filesystem_based_cache_stores).